# Rotating vector grid in QGIS 3.10 vs 3.8

Tags: vector-grid, rotate, qgis-3

Just wondering if anyone else has had an issue with vector rotation via the advanced editing tools in 3.10?

I have a vertical grid overlaying Vancouver Island that I had tried to rotate using the advanced edit tools in QGIS 3.10. Rotating the grid sends QGIS into spinning wheel of infinite loops.

Doing the same task in 3.8 is not a problem.

Just thought I would check here before submitting a bug.

Here are the GeoPackage files in case anyone wants to test.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H8mld8fLWkqnqUqpVa1dlkhnuw1H1kAe/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Wow there is a full team of editors here! Praise be t o editors!